# AndroidJUnitRunner doesn't run tests in package

Tags: java, android, junit, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I'm able to run the instrumentation tests just if I specify the class.

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e class com.application.instrumentation.BaseActivityTest com.application.debug.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner

com.application.instrumentation.BaseActivityTest:.

Time: 2.204

OK (1 test)
```

All my instrumentation tests located in `com.application.instrumentation` package. When I'm trying to run all tests in this package, instrumentation can't locate any test.

```
adb shell am instrument -w -r -e package com.application.instrumentation com.application.debug.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: stream=

Time: 0

OK (0 tests)


INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: -1
```

Same for `AndroidStudio` - I'm able to run tests in specific class and not in the whole package.

**BaseActivityTest.java**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class BaseActivityTest
            extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<BaseActivity> {

    private BaseActivity mActivity;

    public BaseActivityTest() {
        super(BaseActivity.class);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        mActivity = getActivity();
    }

    @Test
    public void checkPreconditions() {
        assertThat(mActivity, notNullValue());
        // Check that Instrumentation was correctly injected in setUp()
        assertThat(getInstrumentation(), notNullValue());
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }

}
```

`AndroidStudio` version is `1.2.2`.

**Test dependencies:**

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

**Available instrumentations:**

```
adb shell pm list instrumentation
instrumentation:com.application.debug.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner (target=com.application.debug)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's because JUnit4-style test classes are not supposed to extend `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<BaseActivity>`. Simply omit that part and do not extend any class, see e.g. [this example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/master/runner/AndroidJunitRunnerSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/testing/androidjunitrunnersample/CalculatorTest.java).